# Detecting overlap with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios

I am using `UIPanGestureRecogniser` on `UIButton`s. I want to detect when two of them overlap in the following way:

```
if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
   [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
   [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {

    CGPoint fingerPoint;

    for(id key in BluetoothDeviceDictionary) {
        UIButton* btn = [BluetoothDeviceDictionary objectForKey:key];
        fingerPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:btn.superview];
    }

    //BLUETOOTH SHARING

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(All buttons from dictionary.frame, fingerPoint)) {

        for the UIButton that has been overlapped do...
```

What is basically happening is that the user drags a `UIButton` onto any other `UIButton` in a series of `UIButton`s on screen that are part of a `dictionary`. When the user releases on any of them, the program has to recognise which one of them has overlapped and the relative `key` from the `dictionary`.

I only can specify one button for `CGRectContainsPoint` and I also don't know how to understand which one of the buttons it was and get the `key` from the `dictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;

if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
   gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
   gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) {

CGPoint dropPoint = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view.superview];

for(id key in BluetoothDeviceDictionary) {
    UIButton* btn = [BluetoothDeviceDictionary objectForKey:key];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(btw.frame, dropPoint)) {
        // overlap - do something...

        // maybe continue or return (if the loop shouldn't continue to test the other buttons
    }
}
```